# VBScript Work out if a person is over 18 based on their Date of Birth

Tags: datetime, vbscript

I have my users DOB as a string (don't ask), how can I reliably check to see if they are over 18? Would I use DateDiff? How would I convert the string to a date first? The date is in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Many thanks
Jonathan

Comment: Have you tried the DontAskDontTell function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
stringDate = "02/12/1990"
if IsDate(stringDate) then
    document.write(DateDiff(yyyy, CDate(stringDate), Date()))
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll need CDate to convert your string and then DateDiff("yyyy",date1,date2) since you only really need the year.

Comment: I need to be accurate with the dob birth as I can't allow under 18s access, our users are all 17 or 18 so I'll need to be sure they are over 18. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed the other pain here, which is that CDate() might need some help with the locale-specific DD/MM/YYYY.   For that, you could parse the constituent parts out and feed them back to CDate(mm.dd.yyyy)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought of first.  Actually... I was wrong on the "yyyy" part. I thought it compared years... but rather, it specifies what is returned... I've deleted the comment for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript's CDate function uses the current locale to convert the date. You may run into problems.

An alternative would be to do it the long way and parse the date out:

```
d = "02/05/1984"

sYear = cint(right(d,4))
sMonth = cint(mid(4,2))
sDay = cint(left(d,2))

ds = DateSerial(sYear, sMonth, sDay)
```

Now you can do your DateDiff:

```
if ( DateDiff( "yyyy", d, ds ) > 18 ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

And what if `d=02/09/1994`, `ds = 26/07/2012`. `datediff("yyyy", d, ds)` gives you 18, but person still not 18, he have to wait few months.
Maybe you need to compare by month?

Answer (score -2):

Take their DOB, add 18 years, and see if the current date is the same or greater.

Comment: The DOB is a string. How is this answer solving the original problem?